# Appcelerator titanium push Notification using C2DM?

Tags: android, titanium, push-notification, appcelerator-mobile

I am using Appcelerator Titanium Version 1.8.0 have anyone tried push notification using google's C2DM.if so help me to create Sample push notification.

Comment: too broad question to answer... Be specific... you can refer kitchen Sink 's example...

Comment: k i refered a code [here](https://github.com/IGx89/titanium-c2dm) but Still i am getting Error like "Module not found " but what my question is I need to create new module or i can simply clone the project code.

Comment: can u tell me steps to implement.I don't want to do big app but sample push notification

Comment: Thank u Maulik i will improve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not that difficult: Here is steps for it...

> 1. Clone project from github
> 2. Find build.properties
> 3. Modify all paths to fit the paths (and versions) in your environment
> 4. Optionally you need to download and install the android sdk from here http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html
> 5. Open console in module root and type ant and hit enter
> 6. The build process should end with something like build successfully
> 7. In the module directory, you will find the build result in the dist folder
> 8. Open that folder, unzip the com.findlaw.c2dm-android-0.1.zip
> 9. A folder is created: modules/android/com.findlaw.c2dm/0.1
> 10. copy the content of modules/android/com.findlaw.c2dm/0.1 to the folder [your_project]/modules/android/com.findlaw.c2dm/
> 11. Copy timodule.xml to the root folder of your project (where the tiapp.xml is located)
> 12. Open tiapp.xml and replace all occurences of com.findlaw.c2dm with your app id, except of the line including this:
>       com.findlaw.c2dm.C2DMReceiver
> 13. Register the module in tiapp.xml:

```
    <modules>
       <module platform="android" version="0.1">com.findlaw.c2dm</module>
     </modules>


 14. Use the module in your code as described in the example of the module
```

For more check [this communication](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/131680/sdk-181-android-modules-problem#answer-231835) of our team member...

Your **Module** folder should not inside the **Resource** folder

[image]

Comment: Thank u maulik after implementing if i get problem may i ask quetion to u

Comment: @sugan.s @maulik would you be able to give me a hand. I followed these instructions and was never able to compile with the following error:  `BUILD FAILED
/Users/administrator/Documents/C2DM/build.xml:9: Cannot find /Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/module/android/build.xml imported from /Users/administrator/Documents/C2DM/build.xml` I also tried the question from Appcelerator and always got the error `unable to find com.findlaw.titanium.c2dm` even after following the instructions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @avivas: at where your module folder is located ?

Comment: @Maulik I just updated my project, was finally able to build it properly. However on the call `c2dm = require('com.findlaw.titanium.c2dm');` I get the following error `Uncaught Error: Requested module not found: com.findlaw.titanium.c2dm` Any ideas?

Comment: @Maulik I was finally able to link and compile but I get a new error.  Would you be able to see my new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018766/c2dm-and-titanium-appcelerator-integration) and see if you can help me out?